# How to protect the token in the client when using OpenId Connect Implicit Flow

Tags: google-analytics, identityserver3, openid-connect

With OpenID Connect implicit flow, the authorization server redirects back to the client after successful authentication. The `location` header will contain the token as url fragment (`#id_token=xyz`).

This protects the token from leaking from the user agent to included resources via referrer or similar.

However, if 3rd party resources like javascript files are included in the redirect target page those scripts would get access to the token via the document location.

What are the best practices to protect the token on client side when including 3rd party ressources? E.g. would you typically implement a 'restricted' redirection target that exchanges url fragment for cookie before redirecting again?

**Update**

To be a bit clearer: in line with the answer by @janhalasa the attack scenario is not inclusion of untrusted javascripts. The line of attack is more inadvertent leaking of the token e.g. to libraries transmitting the document uri to an external server (google analytics?). By moving the hash fragment to session storage it cannot be accidentally leaked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't trust external libraries you are using, it's probably better to stop using them. Wherever you hide the ID token (cookie, sessionStorage, localStorage) using your JavaScript code, the libraries will be able to find it, because both your code and the library code run in the same runtime environment.

I think the common practice is to keep the token in the `sessionStorage` and you attach it only to the requests that require it. The `sessionStorage` has the advantage of being able to survive reload/redirect and is accessible only by the document of your application.